# OpenAPI discriminator - Strongly typed code generation for c#

Tags: c#, openapi

I'm developing an API where a single method will generate concrete subtypes based on a type parameter. I understand that OpenAPI 3 supports this by using oneOf and discrimination.

However, I'm having troubles to see how to end up with a concrete strongly typed class with code generators. The most advanced version I found so far is openapi-generator, but the resulting code seems to be merging the properties of the subtypes in a single model. This is not concrete and not elegant in my opinion.

Let's take this an example:

```
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          discriminator:
            propertyName: powerSource
            mapping:
              electricity: ../components/schemas/ElectricVehicle.yaml
              gasoline: ../components/schemas/FueledVehicle.yaml
              human-energy: ../components/schemas/PedaledVehicle.yaml
          anyOf:
            - $ref: ../components/schemas/ElectricVehicle.yaml
            - $ref: ../components/schemas/FueledVehicle.yaml
            - $ref: ../components/schemas/PedaledVehicle.yaml
```

A general get would return the concrete properties of, for example, ElectricVehicle with powerSource property set to "ElectricVehicle".

Now the question is, how would you manage to do the mapping on c# side? A custom made solution similar to this would work (pseudo code):

```
if (Model.PowerSource == "ElectricVehicle")

    ElectricVehicle electricVehicle = Deserialize<ElectricVehicle>(getResult);

if (Model.PowerSource == "FueledVehicle")

    FueledVehicle fueledVehicle = Deserialize<FueledVehicle>(getResult);

...
```

Is there a better approach than this or this is the correct way to do this? Do you know any openAPI code generator that would deal with such situation correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OpenApi Generator is pretty much the standard, I don't think you will find a better one. It's extensible though and you can write your own "language" generator. Lots of work though.

We could generate decent code by defining the base class:

In Vehicle.yaml:

```
type: object
properties:
  powerSource:
    type: string
discriminator:
  propertyName: powerSource
```

In ElectricVehicle.yaml:

```
allOf:
  - $ref: .\Vehicle.yaml
    type: object
    properties:
    ...
```

In the endpoint you return not `anyOf` but the `Vehicle` type.

This has however the problem that if your definition is split into multiple files, which as I see it is, the inherited files probably won't be picked up, because they are not referenced directly from the parent and are therefore not found when bundling multiple files. You could solve this by adding extra references to the inherited files in your main spec:

```
components:
  schemas:
    ElectricVehicle:
      $ref: components/schemas/ElectricVehicle.yaml
```

However, even after we had a workable C# code, we still had to give up on inheritance and use composition in our APIs, because the same problem came up when generating client code from the same definition. If your client is also C# than it may be ok. I don't remember the details, I think it was usable for Android but a complete rubbish for iOS Swift.